# How to align a div to lower left corner in css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a message box at the lower left corner of the browser window. I want the div to remain stuck to the lower left corner. So if I make the browser smaller it will not disappear. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ap7pg7c7/) I am working with. But it's not working. How can it be done in css? Here is my css code:

```
#lowerleft
{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left : 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at position; in this case position: fixed; bottom: 0;
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

```css
#lowerleft
{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left : 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    color: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="lowerleft">
    I am stuck to lower left border of browser. And I am stuck at the top of lower boundary of te browser.
</diV>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted :D

Answer (score 3):

```
#lowerleft
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left : 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    color: green;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ap7pg7c7/5/)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly served my purpose

Answer (score 1):

To your `css` add this:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ap7pg7c7/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `absolute` positioning (syntax example below):

```
#lowerleft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

What you are currently doing is modifying the `margin` of the element. This only has an effect on the elements **surrounding** the subject.

Using `absolute` positioning places the subject div on top of everything else, having **no effect** on surrounding elements.

Find out about `absolute` positioning from the w3Schools site [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).